# foundation 5 middle columns inside different rows next to each other

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have two rows and inside each one three large columns and only one that reamains visible on medium breakpoint. What I want is to have them float next to each other on medium while breaking to different rows on large and retaining their properties(background and height)?  Also I want the second row to be grouped in div, not necessary with the class of row because what if that div is footer and I care for semantics.

Here is my first pen with two rows separated and it works as expected but not desired,  not allowing divs to float next to each other on medium:
[two separate rows, case one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwgBpO)
html and css for case one:

```
    <body>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="biggest columns large-4 show-for-large-up">row1 height100</div>
        <div class="average columns medium-6 large-4">row1 height50</div>
        <div class="smallest columns large-4 show-for-large-up">row1 height25</div>
      </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="biggest columns medium-6 large-4">row2 height100</div>
        <div class="averge columns large-4 show-for-large-up">row2 height50</div>
        <div class="smallest columns large-4 show-for-large-up">row2 height25</div>
      </div>
     </body>



 /* css for case no.1 */


        .row:first-of-type{background:red;}
        .row{background:blue;}

       /* different height for divs inside row */
        .biggest{height:100px;}
        .average{height:75px;}
        .smallest{height:50px;}
```

and this is pen no.2:
[row inside row, second case](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdbjLg), the following css and html code for case no.2:

```
<body>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="biggest columns large-4 show-for-large-up">row1 height100</div>
          <div class="average columns medium-6 large-4">row1 height50</div>
          <div class="smallest columns large-4 show-for-large-up">row1 height25</div>
          <div class="row">
           <div class="biggest columns medium-6 large-4">row2 height100</div>
          <div class="averge columns large-4 show-for-large-up">row2 height50</div>
        <div class="smallest columns large-4 show-for-large-up">row2 height25</div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </body>

css from code no.2 remains the same like in first example:

    .row:first-of-type{background:red;}
    .row{background:blue;}

    /* different height for divs inside row */
    .biggest{height:100px;}
    .average{height:75px;}
    .smallest{height:50px;}
```

This second example works correct partially. On the medium size code works ok (height of the elements are being respected but on the large size foundation has rule for .row .row that adds negative side margins, but the bigger problem is vertical alignement of floated elements  which takes precedence over horizontal alignement displaying my inner row rather ugly. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using a html table for this?

Comment: No I haven't, I 've used inline-block for the inner row but the result wasn't good. It maybe makes sense to use tables eventhough it is always said that tables aren't for layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed blue div for simplicity. First part is just a normal layout, and it breaks on large, float on medium:
http://codepen.io/zlajaa1/pen/qdWLmd

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="biggest columns medium-4 large-12">row1 height100</div>
        <div class="average columns medium-4 large-12">row1 height50</div>
        <div class="smallest columns medium-4 large-12">row1 height25</div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Now I didn't quite understand what do you want here. Should the medium size float, and on large screens to have them (divs) collapsed or you want to delete some of them, coz I noticed

`<div class="averge columns large-4 show-for-large-up">row2 height50</div>`

show-for-large-up class, that removes divs that has it on medium sizes.

Comment: The whole point is to have two rows with three elements that stay in separate rows on large size allowing its columns (each row has three equal columns on large size) to flow next to each other, but when on medium size each rows should hide two of its columns allowing the two that stay on medium size to blend together into one row

Comment: Yes that is the result I've been looking for. Thank you very much for your answer...